# not well formed,XML parsing

Tags: xml, parsing

this file is a snippet of another bigger HTMl file and when I am opening the file, this snippet is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="images/barsmall.jpg" alt="Pictures of Bar" class="img-responsive visible-xs"> </img>
    </div>

    <div id="tiles" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="Pages/Drinks.html">
                <div id="Drinks-tile"><span>Drinks</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="Pages/Menu.html">
                <div id="Menu-tile">
                    <span>Menu</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/x5whuKnRtfo" target="_blank">
                <div id="Map-tile">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d3559.9186024104656!2d75.56460250705483!3d26.84254113903228!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1538254945957" width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe><span>Map</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>          
    </div>
</html>
```

It says that their is an error (XML parsing error:not well formed) in the 22nd line i.e. the line starting with tag iframe.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` element has a malformed attribute, `allowfullscreen`.  (It has no value.)

Add a value to fix it: `allowfullscreen=""`